# C++ recv asyncronous server-client

Tags: c++, server, client, chat

I'm making a basic chat program and I have an issue.
I wanted to ask if the recv(socket, buf, buflen, 0) is asynchronous in c++? I'm using it in a while loop and it blocks the loop until the server doesn't sends datas to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A socket uses **blocking I/O** by default. If you want to use **non-blocking I/O**, you have to explicitly enable it, by using [`ioctlsocket(FIONBIO)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573.aspx) on Windows, or [`fcntl(O_NONBLOCK)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) on other platforms. I/O operations will then fail with a detectable error (`(WSA)EWOULDBLOCK`, `EAGAIN`, `EINPROGRESS`, etc) if it would block the caller, so you can repeat the operation at a later time.

Alternatively, you can use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to wait for a socket to be in a readable/writable state before performing a read/write operation that would otherwise block.  Or, on some platforms, you can use `setsockopt()` to enable `SO_RCVTIMEO`/`SO_SNDTIMEO` timeouts for blocking reads/write operations.

If you want **asynchronous I/O** instead (start an operation and it completes in the background and then notifies you when finished), you have to either move the I/O to a separate worker thread, or on Windows you can use some extended socket functions ([`ConnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx), [`WSARecv()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688.aspx), [`WSASend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203.aspx), etc) that support Overlapped I/O and I/O Completion Ports.

Comment: I've just realized I haven't thanked you for your response, I apologize for that. I immediatelly correct my mistake and I want to thank you now. Sooooo.. thank you!